# rails console returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-console

I am trying to extract a date from rails console when an operational last occured though it keeps returning nil

when checking a specific value (expire_at)

```
[10] pry(main)> User.last.store_credit.expire_at
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  StoreCredit Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "store_credits".* FROM "store_credits" WHERE "store_credits"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 2]]
=> nil
```

when displaying all fields

```
[12] pry(main)> User.last.store_credit
  User Load (3.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  StoreCredit Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "store_credits".* FROM "store_credits" WHERE "store_credits"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 2]]
=> #<StoreCredit:0x007fab4b5ba6a0 id: 2, amount: #<BigDecimal:7fab4b5b9930,'0.2E2',9(18)>, user_id: 2, expire_at: nil, last_expired_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

but when i run this query i get the values appearing

```
SELECT t.* FROM public.store_credits t
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your User and StoreCredit relationships code? (has_one, has_many, belongs_to, ...)

Comment: Aren't those two separate tables? because you are doing `SELECT  "store_credits".* FROM "store_credits"` and `SELECT t.* FROM public.store_credits t`. Aren't those two tables with the same name but from different schemas?

Comment: same tables, same schema

Comment: @Bustikiller store credit model is `belongs_to :user` user model is `has_one :store_credit`

Comment: Where do you get the word "public" from in your hand made query?

Comment: ignore the fact that it has public in it, the query is referencing the same data source and tables